# Two webhooks with the same URL

Tags: shopify, webhooks

If I have two Shopify apps that have configured webhooks pointing to the same URL for the same events - when one of those events gets fired, will my webhook get fired once, or twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created two Webhooks, one for each App. Hence two Webhooks will fire, one for each App. It does not matter what the end point specified is.